# Spectral measure for symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space and $A$ be a bounded linear self-adjoint operator on $H$. Let $\mathcal M_b(\sigma(A))$ denote the $\mathbb R$-vector space of bounded Borel measurable functions $\sigma(A)\to\mathbb R$. We know that there is a unique continuous algebra homomorphism $\Phi:\mathcal M_b(\sigma(A))\to\mathfrak L(H)$ with $\Phi(1)=\operatorname{id}_H$ and $\Phi\left(\operatorname{id}_{\sigma(A)}\right)=A$. The spectral measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ associated with $A$ is given by $$E:\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\to\mathfrak L(H)\;,\;\;\;B\mapsto\Phi\left(1_{\sigma(A)\:\cap\:B}\right).$$

Now assume $H=\mathbb R^d$, $d\in\mathbb N$ and let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ denote the pairwise distinct eigenvalues of $A$, $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$. We know that $$A=\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i\pi_i,\tag1$$ where $\pi_i$ denotes the orthogonal projection from $\mathbb R^d$ onto $\mathcal N(\lambda_i-A)$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$. Let $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Since $\sigma(A)=\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k\}$, $$E(B)=\sum_{i=1}^k\Phi\left(1_{\{\lambda_i\}\:\cap\:B}\right)\tag2.$$

> While it intuitively should hold, I can't figure out how we see that $$E(B)=\sum_{\substack{1\le i\le k\\\lambda_i\in B}}\pi_i.\tag3$$

Maybe we need to note that, by $(1)$, $A$ is the sum of bouned linear self-adjoint operators with closed range, but I don't see how the defining properties of $\Phi$ yied $(3)$.

Comment: You have $\Phi(f) = \sum_i f(\lambda_i)\pi_i$. Your formula for $E(B)$ pops right out from this.

Comment: @amsmath Thank you for your comment, but then my question is how we see that your formula for $\Phi(f)$ holds.

Comment: Show that the above $\Phi$ is an algebra homomorphism with $\Phi(1) = I$ and $\Phi(\operatorname{id}) = A$.

Comment: @amsmath I only see that the formula is true if $f$ is a polynomial and hence (by approximation) if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: ??? WHy don't you just follow my advice? Is my $\Phi$ an algebra homomorphism? Does it satisfy the two conditions? If yes, my $\Phi$ equals your $\Phi$ by uniqueness.

Comment: @amsmath Since I'd hoped that it would simply follow from the definition. And in fact, it does. Since $\sigma(A)$ is discrete, $f_i(x)=1_{\{x=\lambda_i\}}$ are continuous functions on $\sigma(A)$.

Comment: Well, that's clear. BTW, what definition do you mean?

Comment: @MaoWao Maybe you've got a special version in mind, but the spectral theorem should hold for Hilbert spaces over $\mathbb R$ as well. See, for example, [Theorem 7.17 in the book of Weidmann](https://books.google.com/books?id=vMvcBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=%22weidmann%22+%22spectral+theorem+%227.17%22&source=bl&ots=LQYXAOnKjF&sig=ACfU3U3rWXDdD_xR0QLZoZaE7ioQj-bNrQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnme7c2YnlAhWHJFAKHWgjBGUQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22weidmann%22%20%22spectral%20theorem%20%227.17%22&f=false).